# where are my mistakes in 2 questions in combinatorics?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 2 questions which that I have reached to an answer but they were wrong. I would be very glad to an explanation why they are wrong :)

first question:
we construct randomly a word of 9 letters from the set {a,b,c,d,e}.what is the probability that the word contains all letters?

my answer: the sample space size is $5^9$ . the word must contain all letters and hence we must place all 5 letters in the 9 letter word which is $\binom{9}{5}$.after that there are 4 empty spaces which any letter can be and its $5^4$.so in total the probability is $\frac{\binom{9}{5}*5^4}{5^9}$.
now I know I can solve this with the complementery event but I would like to know why this answer is wrong.

second question:we organize the 10 digits 0-9 in line.what is the probability that there is no 7 following digits increasing sequence? for example 9012345687 contains the above sequence (0123456).

my answer:So I begun with the sample space size which is $10!$ and counted manually every increasing sequnce with 7 or more increasing digits and used it as the complementery event which I got $1-\frac{87}{10!}$(the answer is $1-\frac{78}{10!}$) . I rememberd also to lessen the sequnces that I have already counted from the shorter.for example:the 10 digits sequence from all the possibilties of 9 following digits increasing sequnce.
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Did you cover inclusion- exclusion counting? These questions are textbook cases for that.

Comment: yea and I can solve it that way, but I want to know where are my mistakes.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We construct randomly a word of $9$ letters from the set $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$.  What is the probability that the word contains all letters?

In your attempt, you chose five spaces so that you could place one representative of each letter.  However, you did not arrange the letters in those spaces.  Had you done so by multiplying $\binom{9}{5}$ by $5!$ your answer would have counted each arrangement multiple times since there must be at least one repeated letter and each arrangement would have been counted as often as each letter appears.  For instance, the word $aabbccdde$ would be counted $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 16$ times since there are two possible representatives for each of the letters $a, b, c, d$.

The best approach to this problem is to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  There are $5^9$ ways to fill the nine positions since there are five possible choices for each position.  From these, we must exclude those selections in which one or more letters is excluded from the word.  There are $\binom{5}{k}$ ways to exclude a letter and $(5 - k)^9$ ways to form a word with the remaining letters.  By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of words in which each of the five letters appears at least once is
$$\sum_{k = 0}{5} (-1)^k\binom{5}{k}(5 - k)^9 = 5^9 - \binom{5}{1}4^9 + \binom{5}{2}3^9 - \binom{5}{3}2^9 + \binom{5}{4}1^9 - \binom{5}{5}0^9$$
Hence, the probability that every letter appears in a randomly generated word of length $9$ is
$$\frac{1}{5^9}\left[ 5^9 - \binom{5}{1}4^9 + \binom{5}{2}3^9 - \binom{5}{3}2^9 + \binom{5}{4}1^9 - \binom{5}{5}0^9\right]$$

Had you wanted to count directly, you would first have to partition nine into five parts.
\begin{align*}
9 & = 5 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1
\end{align*}
For each such case, you would have to select how often each letter appears and where it appears in the word.  To illustrate, let's consider the case in which one letter appears three times, two letters appear twice, and two letters appear once.

Choose which of the five letters appears three times.  Choose three of the nine positions for that letter. Choose which two of the remaining four letters each appear twice.  Choose two of the remaining six positions for the selected letter which appears first in an alphabetical list.  Choose two of the remaining four positions for the other selected letter.  The remaining two letters must each appear once.  Arrange them in the remaining two positions.  There are
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{9}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}2!$$
such arrangements.

If you do a direct count for each of the other four cases, then add the results, you should get the same answer as you would by using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

> We arrange the $10$ digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.  What is the probability that there are no increasing sequence of seven consecutive digits?

You have not explained how you counted the sequences with at least seven increasing digits, but it looks like you missed some.  Did you remember to permute the remaining digits? Did you account for the position of the increasing sequence?

Again, you can solve the problem using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Let $A_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, denote the set of permutations which have an increasing sequence of seven consecutive digits beginning in the $i$th position.

$|A_1|$:  The increasing sequence of seven consecutive digits must have lowest digit $0, 1, 2$, or $3$.  For each such choice, there are $3!$ ways to arrange the remaining three digits in the remaining three positions.  Hence,
$$|A_1| = 4 \cdot 3! = 4!$$

By symmetry, $|A_1| = |A_2| = |A_3| = |A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2|$:  For this to occur, there must be an increasing sequence of eight consecutive digits.  The increasing sequence of eight consecutive digits must have lowest digit $0, 1$, or $2$.  For each such choice, there are $2!$ ways to arrange the remaining two digits in the remaining two positions.  Hence,
$$|A_1 \cap A_2| = 3 \cdot 2! = 3!$$

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2| = |A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_3 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_3|$:  For this to occur, there must be an increasing sequence of nine consecutive digits.  The increasing sequence of nine consecutive digits must have lowest digit $0$ or $1$.  For each such choice, there is one way to place the remaining digit in the remaining position.  Hence,
$$|A_1 \cap A_3| = 2 \cdot 1! = 2!$$

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_3| = |A_2 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_4|$:  For this to occur, all ten digits must appear in increasing order.  There is one such sequence.  Hence,
$$|A_1 \cap A_4| = 1$$

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$:  For this to occur, there must be an increasing sequence of nine consecutive digits.  We showed above that this can occur in $2!$ ways.  Hence,
$$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 2!$$

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4|$:  For this to occur, all ten digits must appear in increasing order.  As we observed above, there is one such sequence.  Hence,
$$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = 1$$

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$:  For this to occur, all ten digits must appear in increasing order.  As we observed above, there is one such sequence.  Hence,
$$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 1$$

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of prohibited sequences is
\begin{align*}
|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4| & = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| + |A_4|\\
                                 & \quad - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_4| - |A_2 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_4| - |A_3 \cap A_4|\\
                                 & \qquad + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| + |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| + |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\
                                 & \quad\qquad - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\
                                 & = 4 \cdot 4! - 3 \cdot 3! - 2 \cdot 2! - 1 + 2 \cdot 2! + 2 - 1\\ 
                                 & = 78
\end{align*}
Since there are $10!$ possible permutations, the probability that a permutation does not contain an increasing sequence of seven consecutive numbers is
$$\frac{10! - 78}{10!} = 1 - \frac{78}{10!}$$

Comment: wow,thanks a lot :) really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here : " the word must contain all letters and hence we must place all 5 letters in the 9 letter word which is $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 9 \\ 5\end{smallmatrix}\right)$"

The number $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 9 \\ 5\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is the number of ways to choose 5 places among 9 for your 5 letters. But which letter in every place ? You have to choose one for each such places.

Secondly (on the same problem), the probelm is that if you are given for example the word **abcdeabcd** which set of 5 do you choose ? 12345 or 56789 ? Such a set is not unique and you must take care of not couting two times the same word.

Comment: thanks :) helped me.